# Why val() is null in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have below script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#dpProject").change(function () {
         var idModel = $(this).val();
         var select = $("#dpYear");
         select.empty();
         $.getJSON("/Project/GetYearsOfProject", { projectId: idModel }, function  (mahaleData) {
             var select = $("#dpYear");
             select.empty();
             $.each(mahaleData, function (index, itemData) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: itemData.Value,
                    text: itemData.Text
                }));
            });//each
            });//json
        alert($('#dpYear :selected').html());


    });
```

Why when i want to alert selected item of dpYear it alerted null??
Even i changed to text() it returned null so.
I used jquery-1.7.1.js.

**EDIT**
I have 2 dropdonwns and one textbox , When Dp1(dpProject) changed Dp2(DpYear) must reload and first item in Dp2 is selected for default, and after loading Dp2 , some methods must called and fill the textbox,So with changin Dp1 , text of the depended on first item Dp2 texbox must change, but selected item of Dp2(dpYear) return me null.

Comment: To select the previous selected value again, add this: `select.val(idModel);`, right after the `$.each()` block.

Comment: It should not return anything, it should select again the item previously selected. Please explain what exactly you **want** to happen.

Comment: I explained on EDIT , I added <code>select.val(idModel);<code> right after  $.each() but alert returned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must use hidden field, On change of first Dp , I must set selected value to a hidden field, I don't know why but in first call always selected value that returned by val() is null .

Answer (score 4):

`getJSON` is asynchronous. It returns immediatly after called, just after you emptied your select. That means it will still be empty by the time the alert is called.

How to access the selected value will depend on **when** you want it: after the ajax request completes, there will be no selected value according to your code. If you want, you can choose one to be selected by default (AFAIK the first one will be selected by default if the list is non-empty and you haven't explicitly chosen one).

Update: since this is the case, accessing the value of the select just after you re-populated the select seems to be the way to go:

```
     $.getJSON("/Project/GetYearsOfProject", { projectId: idModel }, function  (mahaleData) {
         var select = $("#dpYear");
         select.empty();
         $.each(mahaleData, function (index, itemData) {
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: itemData.Value,
                text: itemData.Text
            }));
         });//each
         alert($('#dpYear').val()); # If mahaleData is non-empty, this should be non-null
      });//json
```

Comment: +1 A detailed answer with changed code would be better but you've got the right point.

Comment: True, but not really relevant - he's resetting the drop down in the callback so guess OP need to **set** the selected value back to what it was.

Comment: @micha thanks. I plan on updating my answer, but I can't suggest any changes until I understand better what the OP is trying to achieve. Clearly, (one of) the objectives of this `change` is to replace the whole contents of the select, so it's no use moving the alert to the ajax callback (since no option will be selected by then).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think so. The project is being changed, and I assume different projects would have different values for the select. But I might be mistaken, let's wait for the OP feedback.

Comment: Indeed, though can't see any reason to read the selected value *again* when it's already there in `var idModel`.

Comment: `idModel` is the selected value of `#dpProject`, but the OP is interested in the selected value of `#dpYear`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr when dpProject is changed , the event change of dpYear doesn't fire.